# select from db with phpoo

Tags: php, function, class, pdo

i guys, where i am again with noob questions
i made before 1 page alone for select data from my db and it works, is this the code:

```
    <?php
$ligacao = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die
("problemas na ligaÃ§ao ao MySQL");
mysql_select_db("test", $ligacao);
$sql = "select nome, telefone from teste";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql, $ligacao);
while ($registo = mysql_fetch_row($resultado)){
      print ("$registo[0] --- $registo[1] <br>");
}      
mysql_close();
?>
```

now i tryed to put that in classes and functions to run safe and i did something like this
in the class folder:

```
    <?php
class vari{
    /* variables needed */
    protected $hostname;
    protected $username;
    protected $dbpass;
    protected $db;
    protected $sql;
    protected $ligacao;
    protected $resultado;
    protected $registo;

    public function liga() {
        $db = new vari;
        $db->hostname = 'localhost';
        $db->username = 'root';
        $db->dbpass = '';
        $db->db = 'mysql_select_db("test", $this->liga)';
        $db->sql = '"select nome, telefone from teste";';
        $db->ligacao = 'mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->dbpass)';
        $db->resultado = 'mysql_query($this->sql, $this->ligacao)';
        $db->registo = 'mysql_fetch_row($this->resultado)';

        mysql_select_db($db->db, $db->ligacao);
        while ($db->registo = 1){
            print ("$db->registo[0] --- $db->registo[1] <br>");
        }
        mysql_close();
}
}
```

and in the index put that:

```
    <?php
include 'class/classes.php';

$data= new vari;

$data->liga();
?>
```

after all that hard work i go to see what hapenned and i have an infinit looping like this:

```
PHP Error Message

Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/test1/class/classes.php on line 24

Free Web Hosting
1[0] --- 1[1] 
1[0] --- 1[1] 
1[0] --- 1[1] 
1[0] --- 1[1] 
1[0] --- 1[1] 
1[0] --- 1[1]
```

what is wrong with that code? i get the meaning of function and class a litle bit, im learning but the problem here is with the variables i think, can you guys help me fix that? sorry for the long post...
and thanks straight away for the awsers ;)
kjonh2

Comment: why you don't use [PDO](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) ? ..

Comment: Why are you trying to use mysql_ extension?

Comment: Personally, I don't see why you spent all this time on all this, using `mysql_`

Comment: And why are you quoting php functions?

Comment: @jeroen I'll buy that. ( *I stand corrected* ) ;-)

Comment: @jeroen I'm not far behind, *cheers* - Oh, and that "I'll buy that"... looks like I'm buyin' lol

Comment: well im learning and i use what i got before, can you show me a good way to go like a good tutorial to see how to put hold code in pdo, i thought that what i did with that classes and funcs was the called pdo lolol

Comment: or just post an exemple of how to do that correct with pdo or something

Comment: Start with the manual, for example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Also your getting an infinite loop because `while ($db->registo = 1){` will always be true, it should be `while ($db->registo == 1){` but then you dont need a while loop

Comment: @LozCheroneツ yeah thanks i've seing the diference now ;)

Comment: guys like i said before, mysql extenssions is the oldest one, and i have an old manual where i was getting indications from, if i understand how it works in the old mysql, it will be easier to transfer to pdo if i know what query means, and fletch and all that...
but im changing now for pdo, got some pages explaining how it works and how to do this and that, im on the good way now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many have pointed out,  you shouldn't be using mysql_, but to answer your question directly, you have this line in your code:

```
$db->db = 'mysql_select_db("test", $this->liga)';
```

well, since `$this->liga` isn't a property, but rather the current method/function name, it just calls itself. You need to move that line further down the code and change it use `$this->ligacao`

Comment: didnt work anyway, but im leaving that mysql back, and im really trying to go on pdo, cause is safer and as im seeing in new tutorials is maybe easier and simple to do... just need to try to understand beter what everything does, im testing like few functions and cheking what they do and how data comes out...
i think im on a better direction now, thnks to everyone btw
will post something more in few hours or days for sure :p thks